# What is the usefulness of Guava's Optional

Tags: java, guava

[`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) is documented as:

> An immutable object that may contain a non-null reference to another
>   object. Each instance of this type either contains a non-null
>   reference, or contains nothing (in which case we say that the
>   reference is "absent"); it is never said to "contain `null`".

Can you help with an example of the usefulness of the `Optional` class? when might I use it as opposed to something else?

Comment: Since you surely did some research before you asked, you also have found [this page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained), right?

Comment: Use it anywhere you would consider using `null` to represent absence.  Simple as that.